# How can I prove that (eqb x y) means x = y

Tags: coq

I'm new in Coq and this task should be easy:

```
forall x: nat, forall y: nat,
x == y = true -> x = y
```

This is small part of bigger task, but I'm pretty stuck on it. I know that the inverse problem much easier to solve. And suggests that such problems are rare.

**Update** after Rodrigo comment

> The proof proceeds by induction on `x` then case analysis on `y`

```
Lemma Obvious: forall x: nat, forall y: nat,
eq x y = true -> x = y.
Proof.
intros x y H.
  induction x as [| x'].
  (* Case x = 0 *)
    destruct y.
    (* Case y = 0 *)
      reflexivity. (* 0 = 0 *)
    (* Case y = S y' *)
      inversion H. (* 0 = S y', I can't explain what I should do in this situation *)
  (* Case x = S x' *)
    destruct y.
    (* Case y = 0 *)
      inversion H. (* S x' = 0 *)
    (* Case y = S y' *)
      rewrite <- IHx'. (* S x' = S y *) 
(* Now S x' = x' and this is looks falsy, but magical inversion didn't work as before. *)
(* rewrite <- IHx' in H... *)
```

Comment: The proof proceeds by induction on `x` then case analysis on `y`.

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro, Thanks for the response. I added some tryings. It would be great if you could give some tactics more appropriate than the inversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this kind of impossible equality between data type constructors, the best tactic is congruence, that implements a decision procedure called congruence closure. I've proved this lemma without put any "case".

```
 Fixpoint beq_nat (x y : nat) : bool :=
   match x, y with
     | O , O => true
     | S n, S n' => beq_nat n n'
     | _ , _ => false                       
   end.

Lemma Obvious: forall x: nat, forall y: nat,
  beq_nat x y = true -> x = y.
Proof.
  intro x.
  induction x.
  intros y H.
  destruct y. reflexivity. simpl in *. congruence.
  intros y H. destruct y.
  simpl in *. congruence. f_equal ; auto.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Coq, two terms that are constructed with different constructors are by definition different terms by the so called Leibniz equality, the one that `_ = _` uses.

For `nat` values, `S _` and `O` are different constructors, so `S n = O` can never be  true.  For `bool`, `true` and `false` are different constructors, so `true = false` can never be true.

You get these kinds of "non-sensical" assumptions when you do case analysis for impossible cases with `destruct`, `induction`, et al.

The tactic to use when you get these kinds of assumptions in the proof context is `congruence`.  It locates a "bad" assumption, and proves that it implies the goal, since any false assumption implies any proposition.

`congruence` is comfortable to use, but you can also create the proof term "by hand".  For instance:

```
Goal  true <> false.
Proof.
    intro C.   (* now we have "C : true = false" in the context *)
    refine (match C with eq_refl => I end).
Qed.
```